# ICSP Circuit Design

Tags: pic, pcb-design, circuit-design, schematics

I am new to PIC programming and wanted to design my own PIC development board. I have borrowed several designs and combined them into one. The board is based on PIC12F683. Is my design OK? Or will it need any other features (safety or other peripherals)?

[image: PIC Board Design]

**EDIT - Revised Board Design**

[image: Revised PIC Board]

Comment: I would remove D2 and put it in series with the 9V supply input. This will provide a reverse polarity protection. D1 is also unnecessary.  When designing the PCB, put C3 as close to the IC1 as possible.

Comment: @RohatKılıç D1 might not be unnecessary. During programming `MCLR/Vpp` will be 10 - 13 V.

Comment: You cannot have C4 without the diode because it will load the Vpp line during programming.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the 100 ohm resistors? They're on the low side if you intend them to isolate external drivers during programming.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

- leave out D2
- put a 1N4004 over the 5V supply (so its shorts a reversed 5V, such a fools-diode has saved many a chip for me)
- put a 1N4004 in series with the 9V input (note that 9V will be on the low side, 12V is more realistic)
- put a reverse 1N4004 over the 7805
- the 100R resistor values might be too low, depending on your programmer. I preferred 1k.
- replace D1 with a high value R (I suggest 22k, depends on your programmer)
- add a 1N4148 to discharge C4 to the +5V
- if you provide room to replace C1 with a 1000uF/35V you can handle both AC and DC wall-wart adapters
- if you make a PCB, include

  - a sea of holes
  - a (coin cell) battery
  - an on/off switch (switch between battery and external power)

Totally unbsolicited advice: forget PICs, take a cheap Cortex. Blue pills are very cheap.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with the go for a cortex bit. Much more user friendly, and powerful, and the m0s are a similar price. There can't be much future for 8bit micro.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! Where do I place the 1N4148 to discharge C4? After the capacitor (facing towards the ground) or before the capacitor (facing towards 5V?)

Comment: Please see my edit. I have made all of the suggested changes (except for the placement of 1N4148 to discharge C4 to +5V), are they correct? Where do I place the 1N4148? Between C4 and ground or between C4 and R1?

Comment: But why do we need a diode there in the first place?

Comment: I have placed the diode. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: D2 is still present, I don't see a reason for it. And connect D1/S1 to R1/C4.

Comment: So D1 goes in between +5V and R1, and the switch is connected to the junction between the capacitor and the resistors?

Comment: No, D1 is parallel to R1, and S1 is parallel to C4.